# How to remove special character but not the SPACE

Tags: javascript

How to remove special character but not the SPACE

I got the Javascript and its working fine..i just can't figure it out how to ignore SPACE correction

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function valid(f) {
!(/^[A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-z&#209;&#241;0-9]/ig,''):null;
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be

```
!(/^[A-z&#209;&#241;0-9 ]*$/i).test(f.value)?f.value = f.value.replace(/[^A-z&#209;&#241;0-9 ]/ig,''):null;
```

Comment: Thank you i got it :) ic3b3rg